# Counting Field Changes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column

I need to setup some type of counter on how many times a field has been changed in my SharePoint list. Is there any way to do this without coding? If so please explain.

Thanks!

Comment: the only way that comes to mind to achieve that would be using an OnUpdating event receiver... but that is obviously coding. Can't think of any other solution. At the bare minimum, you could try a javascript based solution, but I don't think a pure configuration one exist

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Yeah and I have no coding background....

Answer (score 0):

Enable List item versioning. You can see all the changes made to the item with the field name. That's a no code solution.

Workflow Solution:

1. Create Counter columns in the list for different fields
2. Create one more list with the exact same columns + lookup column on the ID of original list
3. Create a workflow which will run on create and edit on original list
4. In the workflow get item from second list based on the ID via help of lookup column on second list
5. If no item exists create one with the exact field values from initial list in second list
6. If item exists, Compare every field from first list and second list
7. If value is not the same increase the counter of that field in First list
8. Update the item in second list with the new values.

Comment: Not really answering the question by itself (he asked for a counter of the number of changes, not a list) but ... yep, I doubt anything more could be done without coding.

Comment: Yeah and I have the version history already enabled and I have manually pulled the data I need but it was VERY tedious.

Comment: @J.McCormick If you can do with workflows I can propose a solution

Comment: @TaranGoel I am more than willing to hear the solution. Please describe what is going on though so I have a better understanding of how to use in my own instance.